# How do I float an image exactly in the center above text inside a box?

Tags: html, css

I can't get this to work :( I'm just trying to float the image slightly outside the box (half in, half out) above the name but in the `center`. What am I doing wrong here?

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.box_info {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}
.box_info_name {
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.box_info_logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
.box_info_name_inside {}
```

```html
<div class="box_info">
  <div class="box_info_name">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="box_info_logo">
    <div class="box_info_name_inside">Name</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ffxyc6d0/1/

Comment: Can you draw a example of what you're after? (e.g. just two rectangles with the text so we can see their relative positions) It's very difficult to know exactly what you want from that description. (Half in on the right side but vertically centred? Horizontally centred but above the text? Half in half out at the top centre?)

Comment: Basically what @RasmusGlenvig showed, except float the image outside of the box a bit...straight up.

Answer (score 1):

If the image is fixed size (not going to change dynamically) you can position it with a negative margin of half the images height, e.g. `margin-top: -85px;` (Take an extra -10px off as well as the half image height since there's 20px of padding on the parent container)

Example below:

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.box_info {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}
.box_info_name {
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.box_info_logo {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -85px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box_info">
  <div class="box_info_name">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="box_info_logo">
    <div class="box_info_name_inside">Name</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try This One :

```css
body{
  margin-top:100px;
}
.box_info{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    min-width: 300px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align:center;
 }
.box_info_name{
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.box_info_logo{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
    text-align:center;
}
.box_info_name_inside{

}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="box_info">
<div class="box_info_name">
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="box_info_logo">
<div class="box_info_name_inside">Name</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with flexbox as well :)

```css
body{
  margin-top:100px;
}
.box_info{
  background: #ccc;
 }
.box_info_name{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.box_info_logo{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -75px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="box_info">

<div class="box_info_name">

<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/fff" class="box_info_logo">

<div class="box_info_name_inside">Name</div>

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to give 'outside the box' answers to questions like this, without using javascript having to change all the margins gets to be a little annoying. So I've tackled it another way. Rather than moving everything around the page why not just make part of the background transparent.

```css
.box_info {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 95px, #DDD 95px);
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}
.box_info_name {
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.box_info_logo {
  text-align: center;
}
.box_info_name_inside {}
```

```html
<div class="box_info">
  <div class="box_info_name">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150" class="box_info_logo">
    <div class="box_info_name_inside">Name</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box_info">
  <div class="box_info_name">
    <img width="150px" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-1rv6qW3mpvA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAS3M/xq0SSZzrgVg/photo.jpg" class="box_info_logo">
    <div class="box_info_name_inside">Andrew Bone</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've used `background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 95px, #DDD 95px);` to say anything after `95px` should be `#DDD` and before that needs to be transparent.

95px is height of the image (150px) divided by 2 (75px) plus the padding of the outer box (20px).

Which is great if the image size stays the same, if you plan on it changing then we might need to look at adding a little javascript.

linear-gradient is not supported in IE6 but is in modern IE as well as Edge, Chrome, and firefox.

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but maybe this is waht you wan't.

I've simply removed the `position: absolute` from your `.box_info_logo` class.

Like this:

```css
body{
  margin-top:100px;
}
.box_info{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    min-width: 300px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-align:center;
 }
.box_info_name{
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.box_info_logo{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align:center;
}
.box_info_name_inside{
  
}
```

```html
<div class="box_info">
  <div class="box_info_name">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="box_info_logo">
    <div class="box_info_name_inside">Name</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I want ..except I want the image to float outside the box to the top ...halfway :)

Answer (score 0):

To keep `.box_info` the same size as that in your jsfiddle example, you can add `position: relative` to this class whilst keeping `.box_info_logo` as `position: absolute`.

```css
body {
  margin-top: 150px;
}
.box_info {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.box_info_name {
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.box_info_logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 50px;
}
.box_info_name_inside {}
```

```html
<div class="box_info">

  <div class="box_info_name">

    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="box_info_logo">

    <div class="box_info_name_inside">Name</div>

  </div>

</div>
```